# Any way to apply global styles for html tags(ul, li, select, a .. ) based on props?

Tags: reactjs

Wanted to know if there's any way to add styles to tags like ul, li based on props. Using styled components i can create wrapped components, but i wanted to of alternate methods
i wanted to know if we can achieve something like this

```
"li": {
   color: (props) => props.color
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)